# Binding a DataGridColumn to a property in the containing UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I want to bind a custom `DataGridBoundColumn` to a property in the containing `UserControl`. This property contains information that tells the column how to generate its content.

This seemed to be easy at first, but the data context in the data grid is changed, and I can't seem to get a reference to the containing user control. Here is what I tried:

1. `ElementName` doesn't work, since the column isn't in the same name scope.
2. Using `x:Reference`, which has worked for me in similar situations, gives an initialization error.
3. Using `FindAncestor` doesn't work, since the column isn't part of the same visual tree.
4. The column doesn't seem to have a property such as `Owner` that gets the containing `DataGrid`.

I can think of only a few ways to solve the problem, and they're all messy or unsatisfactory:

1. Trying to find the reference through code in the column. This goes against the point of having the column, which is reusing it in a few different contexts.
2. Create a static resource `Dummy` with a dependency property `Value` that is bound to the user control using the `x:Reference` extension, and then bind the column to the static resource, finding the required property using `Path`. *This is what I'm doing now*

Comment: You can use a proxy for the inheritance of DataContext discussed [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).